# Как описать в doctrine orm id genarator при

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

Только изучаю doctrine-orm. Можно ли как то описать такую генерацию первичного ключа в postgresql?

```
create sequence requests.seq_uuid
    increment by 1
    minvalue 1
    maxvalue 9223372036854775807
    start 1
    cache 1
    no cycle;

create or replace function requests.uuid() returns uuid
as $$
begin
    return ('0000000000000000' || lpad(to_hex(nextval('requests.seq_uuid')), 16, '0'))::uuid;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


create table requests.request (
    id uuid not null default requests.uuid(),

    request text,
    constraint request_pk primary key (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо создать свой класс, унаследованный от `AbstractIdGenerator`:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;

class MyIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        return $em->getConnection()->executeQuery('select requests.uuid() as uuid;')->fetchOne();
    }
}
```

И создать класс `entity` со следующим определением первичного ключа:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="requests.request")
 */
class Request
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="MyIdGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
```